# CySCA2014 Random

Tags: kali-linux, gimp

I am doing a research regarding the Cyber Security Challenge Australia 2014. Since there are provide solution on their official website, I am just follow their steps to complete each the of the challenges and write out my own report.
But I am encounter some issue during the progress.

[CySCA2014 Random](https://www.cyberchallenge.com.au/pdf/CySCA2014_Random.pdf)

When I am doing the first sub-challenge of it, it have 2 solution:-
Using GIMP or either or rebuild the header. My Kali VM can't download anything or connect to any website, because it was copied and paste from my university lab.

It said "We create a test bitmap to and use hexdump to extract the header bytes." 
Can I know like what test.bmp to create? I have tried create several test.bmp but still can't get the expected result.
Any advise?

Comment: They just use this file to get a valid BMP header, so the actual file content shouldn't matter. The BMP version might matter, but this depends on how you created the test.bmp file. Can you describe that, provide a test.bmp file you have created, and the corresponding hexdump output?

Comment: I had tried to create a test.bmp from a valid jpg file and it cannot be view, create empty content test.bmp file also cannot be viewed. However, I'll take a shot with download some random bmp file to test it

Comment: You do realize that renaming a file to test.bmp won't magically convert the format?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Thanks for help. I just did with random google image and couldn't get the correct image out. But when I try with bigger image such 1600x900 bmp image and execute the script. I got the correct result.

Comment: Please consider to work on your question-asking skills. Your question should allow someone else to exactly reproduce what you have done, and get an idea of what problems you have encountered. This means telling others the commands you used, enable them to get the same files you have used, and so on. Have a look at e.g. http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise - for example, you still didn't specify how exactly you created the bmp files you were working with.